# ValidationException: The table does not have the specified index: GameTitleIndex

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, vogels

I am using Vogels, DynamoDB data mapper for NodeJS. I am querying against a **global index** according to the Vogels' documentation. All I have done is, created a model with a global secondary index like this:

```
let MyModel = vogels.define('MyModel', {
  hashKey: 'uuid',
  timestamps: true,
  updatedAt: 'updated_at',
  createdAt: 'created_at',
  schema: MyModelBaseSchema,
  indexes : [{ 
    hashKey : 'gameTitle', rangeKey : 'topScore', name : 'GameTitleIndex', type : 'global'
  }]
});
```

and querying against this index

```
MyModel.query('game 1')
  .usingIndex('GameTitleIndex')
  .loadAll()
  .select("COUNT");
```

When running any tests it shows an exception `ValidationException: The table does not have the specified index: GameTitleIndex`

According to the documentation, this is all I have to do to get data. Is there anything which I have missed to query this index?
Any answers will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone's stuck at the same issue, here is the answer:
After creating a new index in model, either local secondary index or global secondary index, Migrations are to be run. Only after then the table will have the specified index. Refer to [this issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby-record/issues/64) for more clarification.

Answer (score 3):

– In case you are using Serverless framework with **serverless-dynamodb-local** and **serverless-offline** plugins (for local testing).

– And in case you are created new **Local Secondary Index**, but the command shown below still not showing it under `LocalSecondaryIndexes` configuration node:

```sh
aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name YOUT_TABLE_NAME --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

– And in case you are receiving error `ValidationException: The table does not have the specified index: YOUR_INDEX_NAME` when using code similar to shown below:

```js
  query(uid, id) {
    const params = {
      TableName: YOUR_TABLE_NAME,
      IndexName: YOUR_LSI_NAME,
      KeyConditionExpression: "#uid = :uid and #id = :id",
      ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#uid": "uid",
        "#id": "id",
      },
      ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":uid": uid, ":id": id },
    };
    return DB.query(params).promise();
  }
```

Then most likely you need to **delete** local DynamoDB database file and restart services with `serverless offline start` command. This will force recreation of local DynamoDB database file with proper **Local Secondary Indexes**.

---

To delete local DynamoDB database file do the following:

1. Update the `serverless.yml` by specifying path to DynamoDB database, like shown below:

```
custom:
  dynamodb:
    stages:
      - ${self:provider.stage}
    start:
      port: 8000
      inMemory: true
      migrate: true
      dbPath: "./.db" # Make sure that folder exists!
```

2. Now you can go to the folder `./.db` and remove file `shared-local-instance.db` (which is a SQLite database which mimics DynamoDB :0).

As result on next start with the command `serverless offline start` the **up to date** local DynamoDB database file will be created.